# Crash while dismissing uiimagepicker

Tags: ios, camera, uiimagepickercontroller, uiview-hierarchy

[image]
This is an issue reported at crashlytics. I am getting this(I assume) when I load image picker and dismiss. I only got this once. But it got something to do with image picker or navigation controller. Does any one know the cause?

**Update**
Image picker camera is loaded like this.

```
    UIImagePickerController *imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagePickerController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
    imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    imagePickerController.delegate = self;
    if([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft)
    {
        [[UIDevice currentDevice]setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight] forKey:ORIENTATION_STRING];
    } else {
        [[UIDevice currentDevice]setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft] forKey:ORIENTATION_STRING];
    }

    self.imagePickerController = imagePickerController;
    [self.navigationController presentViewController:self.imagePickerController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

for other source types, I am using the following code.

```
UIImagePickerController *imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
imagePickerController.sourceType = sourceType;
imagePickerController.delegate = self;
popOver = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:imagePickerController];
self.imagePickerController = imagePickerController;
popOver.delegate = self;
CGRect popOverRect = sender.frame;
[popOver presentPopoverFromRect:popOverRect
                         inView:self.view
       permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionRight animated:YES];
```

Comment: Add your Code here..!!

Answer (score 0):

Add UIIMagePickerController to ContainerView. & then to view

```
UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.delegate = self;
picker.allowsEditing = YES;
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
picker.mediaTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: (NSString *)   kUTTypeMovie, nil];

[self addChildViewController:picker] ;

[picker didMoveToParentViewController:self] ;

[self.view addSubview:picker.view] ;
```

while removing pickercontroller do

```
[picker.view removeFromSuperview] ;
[picker removeFromParentViewController] ;
```